# Как загрузить несколько dll на c# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dllimport

Занимаюсь разработкой виртуальной машины на C# используя .NET Core 1.1. Для неё есть специальные исполняемые файлы в которых прописаны названия подключаемых dll библиотек (и не только, но это не суть). Все эти библиотеки находятся в папке vmlib. Каждая из них имеет главный класс наследуемый от VMLibrary и имеют название библиотеки, например System, и имеют метод Load не принимающий аргументов. Названия библиотек в исполняемом файле моей виртуальной машине написаны через запятую. То есть например пользователь указал 2 библиотеки "sys, tex" и вм (виртуальная машина) должна их найти в папке vmlib, затем в каждой библиотеке найти главный класс и выполнить метод Load. 
Подскажите как реализовать такое, потому что после долгих поисков в интернете я ничего подобного не нашёл :(

Comment: Думаю вам нужен класс Assembly. Обычно метод LoadFile, но для .NET Core 1.1 доступен метод Load http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netframework-4.8 а дальше имеея сборку - рефлексия, получение модуля, класса, метода - и вызов Invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй что-нибудь вроде такого

```
string dllPath = "путь к vmlib";
string dllSource = "имена библиотек через запятую";
Type mainType = typeof(VMLibrary);
var dllNames = dllSource.Split(',').ToList();
foreach (var dllName in dllNames)
{
    var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(Path.Combine(dllPath, dllName));
    var mainClass = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t != mainType && mainType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
    if (mainClass != null)
    { 
        var mainObj = Activator.CreateInstance(mainClass) as VMLibrary;
        if (mainObj != null) mainObj.Load();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вариант рабочий, но у меня траблы с System.Runtime.Loader, есть ли другой способ?

Comment: @snaulX а что с ним не так?

Comment: если не добавить его через NuGet то компилятор его не видит, а если добавить, то создаёт FileNotFoundException System.Runtime.Loader не найден, несмотря на то что она есть (в ручную проверял). А если dll с System.Runtime.Loader запихнуть в папку с бинарниками то BadImageException

Comment: @snaulX это странно, по идее он поддерживается с .net core 1.0. Возможно не поддерживается в конкретных типах проектов конечно. Тогда в принципе можно всё оставить как есть, а саму загрузку сборок взять из комментария к вопросу.

Comment: В качестве альтернативы я нашёл `Assembly.LoadFrom` и он мне подходит. А так спасибо за ответы и советы!